# Make a repair in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

We have a cluster of 9 nodes, each node with 300 GB (Version `Cassandra 3.11`), we have performed full repairs on each one of them, and they have been completed correctly, but we still have 3 nodes to repair, but the repair never ends.

They could indicate the good practices that we must carry out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We need good practices on how to perform a nodetool repair to our cluster

Answer (score 0):

either execute: "nodetool repair -pr --full" on each node sequentially or check out Cassandra Reaper tool, which does the job.